# What to use instead of UNet?

Tags: unity, multiplayer, unet

If you look at this [Link](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/08/02/evolving-multiplayer-games-beyond-unet/) you'll see UNet is deprecated and will be removed in the future.

I'm developing a mobile multiplayer game, i've red official advise about it but they say "You can publish it with 2018.4 (LTS)" and I can't use 2018.4 version because in my project i use LWRP which is not in the 2018.X versions.

I've found the alpha version of the new system right [here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/multiplayer)

My questions are:

1- Should i use the alpha version of the new system? And can i publish my game with it?

2- Should i wait for the new system came out? (I can't wait for months)

3- Should i try to use other third party systems like Photon?

Or is there any way to publish my game with nice multiplayer system?

**Note:** I can't pay for multiplayer matchmaking system. Because of that i want to make Hosting multiplayer game.

Comment: Questions about which technology/library/framework to use are not on-topic for this particular Exchange. Can you edit your question to frame it in terms of "here's a particular operation or step I don't know how to perform / how can I implement this specific behaviour?" ?

Comment: While UNet is no longer supported, it is still functional. Unity's new networking system is quite a ways off. So either use UNet, but you are on your own if you have troubles, use their new one in early preview, but suffer the early adopter's price, or use something third party (of which is probably based on UNet). In short, there isn't a great solution at the moment. We are in limbo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure why not Photon2(PUN) is currently the number one platform used by professional studios and developers.
As Unet being deprecated by Unity Photon is claiming to be the number one platform to create real-time multiplayer games. Recently Photon changed the implementation in Photon2 with better and optimized and well-structured code.

I think you should use the free version of Photon2(PUN), You can use it very easily and also it is Fast, reliable and scalable.

check these links:

https://www.photonengine.com/
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rF2JGhv3Pyo

and also you can learn how to use it with:

https://paladinstudios.com/2014/05/08/how-to-create-an-online-multiplayer-game-with-photon-unity-networking/
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=evrth262vfs

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort i'll try Photon2, hope i can make it.

Comment: One last question, if I use Photon2 free version, and code my multiplayer system hosting based. Do i pay anything for multiplayer or not?

Comment: No, I don't think so, check the link below:
https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/server/current/operations/licenses